# What is this phenomenon called, "I had a dream that I was having a dream"?

Tags: vocabulary

I don't know if anyone of you have these kind of dreams before; I'm dreaming then suddenly I dream that I wake up from that dream.

Then, sometimes (admittedly rarely, though it's rather fun) it could chain a couple of times, like I dream that I wake up from my dream, then after that I dream that I wake up from that dream in which I am dreaming I wake up from my dream. And the cycle repeats once more.

What's this phenomenon called?

Comment: *Recursion*, maybe? :)

Comment: @Whirlwin: Did you mean [recursion](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS437US437&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=recursion)? ^_^

Comment: It's called 'watching Inception before going to bed'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are talking about [false awakening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_awakening).

> A false awakening is a vivid dream about awakening from sleep. After a
>   false awakening, subjects often dream they are performing daily
>   morning rituals such as cooking, cleaning and eating. The experience
>   is sometimes called a double dream, or a dream within a dream.

Comment: lol looks like i had a quidruple dream

Comment: It's particularly annoying when you do a lot of housework or similar and then find you have to wake up and do it again!